# What is the probability that a man likes pink?

Tags: probability

How would you solve this probability problem?

> Group of men are playing game. Each rolls a dice.
>
> If the number is 1, he must say "I like pink" regardless of his true taste and
>
> If the number is 2, he must say " I don't like pink" regardless of his true taste.
>
> If the number is 3,4,5 or 6, he must tell his true taste.

Assuming that 2/3 of men answered "I like pink", what is the probability that a man actually likes pink?

Comment: To clarify;  are you saying that $\frac 23$ of all men answer "I like pink" or are you saying something else?

Comment: 2/3 of men playing this game answered "I like pink". Meaning, 1/3 answered "I don't like pink". in that 2/3 of men, there are poeple who actually like pink and answered yes, and people who don't like pink and had to say they do.

Comment: That's what I figured.  I've written something and posted it below.  Does it make sense?

Comment: Note that my answer is assuming the question meant "two out of three men answered they like pink".

Comment: Do we need to know a prior probability that a man likes pink?  Suppose that it were exceedingly rare for a man to like pink.  Then, we would conclude with very high confidence that the men who answered "I like pink" had rolled a 1, and that (with very high probability) no men in the group like pink.

Comment: When you say, "what is the probability that a man actually likes pink", do you mean, "what is the probability that at least one of the men who played in this game actually likes pink"?

Comment: @littleO To your first question, no, the prior probability that a man likes pink is irrelevant. For the second one, It means, what is the probability that a game playing man chosen at random actually likes pink.

Comment: Spoo himpo gardoofgonghopukabankcoopholuinghoppy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\psi$ be the probability that a randomly chosen man likes pink. Of course we assume that his taste in colors is independent of his dice roll.

Knowing that a man says "I like pink" we know that either he threw a $1$ or he threw $\{3,4,5,6\}$ AND likes pink.  Thus your conditions come to:

$$\frac 23=\frac 16+\frac 46 \times \psi\implies 4 = 1+4\psi\implies \psi=\frac 34$$

Comment: Is this answer assuming that if a randomly selected man plays this game, then his probability of saying "I like pink" is $2/3$?

Comment: @littleO  Yes it is. I agree that the original question was ambiguous.  In the comments I asked if my reading was what was intended, and the OP confirmed that it was.

Comment: This is the correct answer in the limit where the size of the group playing the game tends to infinity (or, equivalently, in the theoretical scenario where we assume 2/3 to be the *a priori* probability of a randomly chosen player to say "I like pink" before they roll the die). If we take 2/3 to be the observed outcome of an actual game played by a finite group of men, however, the outcome will have some variance that will affect the estimate of the underlying fraction of men that like pink. [...]

Comment: [...] Also, for such "inverse" problems, where we wish to estimate an underlying parameter from noisy observed data, the estimate will partly depend on our prior assumption about how likely each underlying fraction would be. (We can try to avoid biasing the estimate by choosing a "neutral" prior assumption, but that's still an assumption.) As the group size increases, this sensitivity to prior assumptions will decrease. Ps. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_response

Answer (score 0):

Note: this question answers the question if "2 / 3 men like pink", interpreted as "2 out of 3 men".  That is different from the current question, which states "2/3 of men", i.e. "two thirds of men".

Let's compute the probability of no man liking pink.  For that to be true, two of men had to roll a 1, and the other one had to roll anywhere from 2 to 6.  The probability is:

5 * (1/6)^3 * (3 choose 2)

Based on this, you should be able to figure out the answer.

Comment: Thanks but could you explain why "two of men had to roll a 6, and the other one had to roll anywhere from 1 to 5" ?.?

Comment: If the men don't like pink, then the only thing that could've forced them to say they do is if they rolled a 1.  On the other hand, the man who said he doesn't like pink either rolled a 2 (and he was forced to say that), or he rolled between 3 and 6, and told the truth.

Comment: @Alex There's *a group* of men playing the game -it is not specified as three-.

Comment: @GrahamKemp This was not clear in the original post at the time I posted my answer, but was edited in later.

Comment: What your formula is computing is the probability that 2 out of 3 men answer "I like pink" when they play the game, given that none of them actually do. This is *not* generally the same as the probability of none of the men liking pink, assuming that two of them say they do when the play the game. Of course, the two probabilities can be related via [Bayes' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem), but this relationship will depend on the unspecified prior probability of $k$ of the men liking pink, before we know the game results.

Comment: (In fact, confusing the probability of an observation, given that an assumption holds, with the probability of the assumption holding given the observation is a well known statistical fallacy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosecutor's_fallacy)