# Nose picking probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> A questionnaire is carried out to find the percentage of men that pick
>   their nose. Since most men are embarrassed to answer this questions,
>   they are told to do the following. Secretly roll a dice. If the number
>   is 1 always say I do not pick my nose regardless of what the truth is,
>   if the number is 2 always say I pick my nose regardless of what the
>   truth is, if the number is 3, 4, 5 or 6 then tell the actual truth.
>   This way, it is not possible to ever be sure which men pick their nose
>   or not. If we assume that 2/3 of men answered I pick my nose, what is
>   the probability that a man picks their nose? If instead we assume that
>   fraction of men that pick their nose is 3/4, what is the probability
>   that a man picks his nose given that he answered I do pick my nose.

So far I have that (for part a). $P(t|y) = \frac{P(y|t)\cdot P(t)}{P(y)}$ where $y=$ yes they pick nose. $t = $ telling the truth... However, I can't find $P(y|t)$ Thanks.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It is a (rephrased) version of:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680859/what-is-the-probability-that-a-man-likes-pink/1680873#1680873

Comment: Seems *slightly* different on reflection.

Comment: "You can pick your friend and you can pick your nose but you can't pick your friend's nose." -- Ben Franklin.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
P(\text{yes})=\overbrace{\frac23P(\text{pick})}^{\text{rolled $3$-$6$ and pick}}+\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \ \frac16\ \ \ \ \ }^{\text{rolled $2$}}
$$

---

There are two disjoint cases where people say yes and are telling the truth:

1. roll $3$-$6$ and pick their nose $=\frac23P(\text{pick})$
2. roll $2$ and pick their nose $=\frac16P(\text{pick})$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{yes }\land\text{ truth})
&=\frac23P(\text{pick})+\frac16P(\text{pick})\\
&=\frac56P(\text{pick})
\end{align}
$$
There are three cases where people tell the truth:

1. roll $3$-$6$ $=\frac23$
2. roll $2$ and pick their nose $=\frac16P(\text{pick})$
3. roll $1$ and don't pick their nose $=\frac16(1-P(\text{pick}))$

Therefore,
$$
P(\text{truth})=\frac56
$$
This makes sense since the only time they wouldn't tell the truth is when they rolled $1$ or $2$ depending on whether they did or did not pick their nose.

Thus,
$$
P(\text{yes}\mid\text{truth})=P(\text{pick})
$$

Answer (score 0):

> If we assume that 2/3 of men answered I pick my nose, what is the probability that a man picks their nose?
>
> If instead we assume that fraction of men that pick their nose is 3/4, what is the probability that a man picks his nose given that he answered I do pick my nose.

First, be clear on the events you are measuring.   Labelling one event "telling the truth" is a misdirection - it is not something you are directly given.   You are comparing what they say and what they do.

You want your $y$ to be the event of saying "I do", and $t$ to be the event of nose picking.

The probability of someone saying **y**es given that they do pick **t**heir nose is $5/6$, by reason that they answer yes on a roll of $\{2, 3,4,5,6\}$.

$$\mathsf P(y\mid t) =\frac 5 6$$

So for (a)

$$\mathsf P(y) = \mathsf P(y\mid t)~\mathsf P(t)+\mathsf P(y\mid \neg t)(1-\mathsf P(t)) \\ \tfrac 2 3 = \tfrac 5 6 \mathsf P(t)+ \tfrac 2 6 (1-\mathsf P(t)) \\ \vdots$$

Comment: But isn't that saying that "given that the men are telling the truth... $\frac{5}{6}$ pick their nose"?

Comment: @BobMingHao The condition is not "telling the truth"; it is  "actually do pick their nose".

Comment: Wouldn't "If we assume that 2/3 of men answered I pick my nose" translate to "given$ \frac{2}{3}$ men said they picked their nose, what is the probability that they are telling the truth"?

Comment: Would the events be the same in both parts?

Comment: @BobMingHao Some of the 1/3 who answer "I don't" can also be telling the truth, so you are not interested in truth-telling.  You want the probability that a man does when 2/3 of men say they do.